# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module index.js not supported

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I'm using [log-update](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-update) and I recently upgraded to version 5.0.0, and change the entire project to work with CommonJS ES6 (import instead of require), and for some reason I keep getting:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\node_modules\log-update\index.js from C:\src\utils\files\log.utils.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\src\utils\files\log.utils.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
  courses\node_modules\@babel\node\lib\_babel-node.js:176:21) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Web
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c babel-node src/scripts/initiate.script.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-01T17_56_21_202Z-debug-0.log
```

I looked at:
[Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081410/error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module-not-supported)
[require() of ES Module not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70097678/require-of-es-module-not-supported)
[Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69621234/error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module)
But none of them working for me.
Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I just converted the project into pure ESM: https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c
And it works for me.